# How to use a custom event fieldsObject

Tags: google-analytics

Let say my endpoint give me response `{success:true,id:1234}`. I want to send this data to Google Analytics on particular event hit. How I can do that?

I tried:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'GetProfile', 'onPageLoad','getprofile',1,this.userdata);

this.userdata = {success:true,id:1234} .
```

I can only see the getprofile as event level and value as 1, but I cannot find where my this.userdata logged

Comment: I don't think you can invent your own field objects like that.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference  following in the event I am wrong.